# Angular 8 ActivatedRoute Params are not getting

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a problem to get an param from url while using ActivatedRoute in angular as i am trying below method.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PartPriceComponent } from './part-price/part-price.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "product/:device", component: PartPriceComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**part-price.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-part-price',
  templateUrl: './part-price.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./part-price.component.css']
})
export class PartPriceComponent implements OnInit {
  public deviceSelectedVal: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
     this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
       (params: any) => {
         this.deviceSelectedVal = params.get('device');
     })
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('this.deviceSelectedVal', this.deviceSelectedVal)
  }
}
```

i am trying to pass in URL like this http://localhost:4200/product/pixel

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to subscribe to params on the activated route. Like this,

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    this.deviceSelectedVal = params['device'];
    console.log('New device detected', this.deviceSelectedVal);
})
```

Add the subscription in ngOnInit lifecycle hook or keep it the way you are adding it in constructor (But the constructor should only be used to initialize class members but shouldn't do actual "work").

Answer (score 0):

`this.route.params.subscribe` is asynchronous, so `console.log('this.deviceSelectedVal', this.deviceSelectedVal)` this will be called before `this.deviceSelectedVal = params.get('device');`

Add your console.log right below `this.deviceSelectedVal = params['device'];`

Comment: Try this but still getting null value

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to update `device` parameter within the same component you are accessing it, then you can just get it from the snapshot.
`this.route.snapshot.paramsMap.get('device')`

Comment: Nikolay i am trying this also but still getting null

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide your logic under ngOnInit. I hope this will resolve your issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
       (params: any) => {
         this.deviceSelectedVal = params.get('device');
     });
}
```

Comment: yes i am trying to build my logic under ngOnInit but still i am  not getting  any thing in params. my params values are getting empty object {}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` component somewhere in your views?

[`RouterOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) "acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state." So, you need it for angular to understand what should be rendered depending on your route.

For example, I have the following route set up:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'test/:id', component: TestComponent},
];
```

My main.ts file has the following code to bootstrap the AppModule:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And the AppModule botstraps the AppComponent:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Inside the app.component.html I only have the RouterOutlet, so that the content is rendered dynamically:

```
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

I'll also mention that I have a base url in the index.html set to "browsertest", just to provide some context. Now, when the url browsertest/test/1 is called, the AppComponent is loaded, and the router outlet inside it does its job rendering (in my case) the TestComponent and resolving the url params (in my case the :id).

In my TestComponent I pass an ActivatedRoute instance in the constructor and catch the id value in the OnInit method (I think I found it in [this guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/11/a-complete-guide-to-routing-in-angular/)):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  id: string | null | undefined = '';
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id');
      });
```

And like that it worked for me. My mistake in the beginning was that I just ignored the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my component.html.

P.S. one more issue that I had was that the router-outlet would duplicate content. This happened because at first I would set the component rendered by the path to AppComponent like that: `{path: 'test/:id', component: AppComponent},];`, and the AppComponent had some content inside. So what would happen is that first the main.ts would bootstrap the AppModule, where the AppComponent with some content AND the router-outlet was bootstraped, and inside the router-outlet thanks to the set up route ANOTHER AppComponent was bootstraped. So I solved it by leaving only the router-outlet in the AppComponent and wrapping the content into another component.